# Python Selenium find_elements by xPATH returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hi I am new in python selenium. I want to extract some information from the following page https://bid.cars/pl/search/results?search-type=filters&type=Automobile&year-from=1900&year-to=2024&make=Jeep&model=Cherokee&auction-type=All
The page returns list of sold cars. Each car has unique identifier (Eg."Numer: 0-35954378"). I want to extract value for all the cars. As a tart point I am trying to extract value 0-35954378.
[Click to display screeshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANn8U.png)  
Via SelectorsHub I retrieved the element Xpath //body[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[1]

My python code looks like below but it returns nothing

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://bid.cars/pl/search/results?search-type=filters&type=Automobile&year-from=1900&year-to=2024&make=Jeep&model=Cherokee&auction-type=All')
all_spans = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value="//div[@class='row']//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[1]")
for span in all_spans:
    print(span.text)
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the wait, it is also a good idea to avoid as much as possible this type of xpath : div[1]//li[2]... In your case you can use the methods available for the selenium elements:

```
list_res= driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'items-row')
vehicles = list_res.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lots-search')
# check if ther is any car in the page
if len(vehicles)==0:
    print("No car in the list")
for vehicle in vehicles:
    item_specs = vehicle.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-specs')
    number = item_specs.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')[0]
    print(number.text)
```

The code is more readable and easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wait until the page loads completely and desired element is visible. You can achieve that by using selenium's `waits`

Try this:

```
all_spans = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[1]//div[2]//div[2]//ul[1]//li[1]")))
for span in all_spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Console output:

```
Numer: 0-35954378

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**UPDATE:** In case you are interested in printing all the elements **Numer:**. Then try the below code:

```
all_spans = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Numer:']//parent::li")))
for span in all_spans:
    print(span.text)
```

Console Output:

```
Numer: 0-35954378
Numer: 0-35259548
Numer: 0-35311342
Numer: 0-35436922
Numer: 0-35362206
Numer: 0-35707354
Numer: 0-35779189
Numer: 0-35994685
Numer: 0-35536329
Numer: 0-35945281
Numer: 0-35873282
Numer: 0-35959753
Numer: 0-35837249
Numer: 0-35776807
Numer: 0-35618989
Numer: 0-35532919
Numer: 0-35631487
Numer: 1-40989193
Numer: 1-43697413
Numer: 1-40468853
Numer: 1-45289353
Numer: 1-45289173
Numer: 1-42777553
Numer: 1-41613883
Numer: 1-72373302
Numer: 1-39444273
Numer: 1-73146322
Numer: 1-42996963
Numer: 1-38210013
Numer: 1-72783072
Numer: 1-39825163
Numer: 1-39480713
Numer: 1-41967373
Numer: 1-38702863
Numer: 1-43687943
Numer: 1-66278552
Numer: 1-35865053
Numer: 1-36381873
Numer: 1-42179823
Numer: 1-42478053
Numer: 1-40804723
Numer: 1-60160692
Numer: 1-42572953
Numer: 1-41972593
Numer: 1-71537212
Numer: 1-39706293
Numer: 1-69067952
Numer: 1-40590473
Numer: 1-42523973
Numer: 1-37934343

Process finished with exit code 0
```